# how to get get the JDBC connection url string

Tags: java, jdbc

I don't know why I can't find this.  My library takes a jdbc connection object and I need to support some different meta-data for different connections (which may be to different databases) so I figure I could use the connection URL string as the key for my map but I can't find it.

Is there any way to get the connection URL string from a connection object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Connection.getMetaData().getURL()` or one of the other methods such as `DatabaseMetadata.getDriverName()` will give you information about the database connection.